# location manager in Android apps

Tags: android

I create simple android apps which show location of device but when I run in emulator it show error in run the apps.

```
package my.loc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        LocationManager manager =
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Location loc =
            manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            textView.setText("latitude: " + loc.getLatitude()
            + "\nlongitude: " + loc.getLongitude());
    } }
```

Activity.xml file is such As

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
         />
```

and manifest is such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.loc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LocActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Error is:

> The application loc has stopped unexpected.

Comment: can you post the error ?

Comment: Also give your `activity.xml` code .

Comment: Also you are missing single `}` after the last `}`. End it properly .

Comment: See my answer in this post   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932388/locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-add-or-update/16932548#16932548

Comment: You say it fails in the emulator; what does it do on a real device? And as Udi says, please post the relevant logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

You must have your class implement `LocationListener` and call `manager.requestLocationUpdates()` in order to obtain location information. See further details at http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html